# Change a screw mount camera to a Bayonet mount or T-mount lenses

Tags: lens, lens-mount, ricoh

I have an old Ricoh 35 mm SLR camera. It uses a Screw mount lens system as oppose to other 35mm cameras that adopted the Bayonet mount system otherwise know as T-mount. I am looking for a conversion ring that will allow my camera to accept T-mount lenses since there are not many Screw mount lenses out their anymore. I have looked on line and have found only converters that will allow me to use cameras with T-mounts to use screw mount lenses but nothing that will fit my needs. Am I wasting my time or  are there converters out there that will meet my needs?

Comment: T-mount has 42mm x 0.75mm pitched threads. Your Ricoh probably uses the M42 mount, which has threads with a pitch of 1.0mm. T-mount *adapters* have a receiver on the front that accepts the 42mm x 0.75mm T-threads and a bayonet on the back that attaches to a specific bayonet mount system.

Comment: What specific Ricoh model do you have?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear because of the T-mount confusion. I _suspect_ as does @xiota that you mean "K-mount", but… maybe not?

Answer (score 2):

#### M42 vs T-mount vs K-mount

It seems you may be confusing [M42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M42_lens_mount), [T-mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-mount), and [bayonet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount) mounts. Per [comment by Michael Clark](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90798/75526#comment161935_90798):

> T-mount has 42mm x 0.75mm pitched threads. Your Ricoh probably uses the M42 mount, which has threads with a pitch of 1.0mm.

Ricoh switched to using the [Pentax K-mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentax_K-mount) in 1977.

#### [Ricoh Cameras](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Ricoh)

The following cameras use the M42 mount:

- [Ricoh Singlex TLS](http://mattsclassiccameras.com/slr/sears-tls-ricoh-singlex-tls/)
- [Ricoh TLS 401 (1970-1976*)](http://www.camera.portraits.srv2.com/ricoh401.htm)

The following cameras use K-mount:

- [Ricoh XR-7](http://mattsclassiccameras.com/slr/sears-ks-2-ricoh-xr-7/)
- [Ricoh KR-5](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Ricoh_KR-5)
- [Ricoh KR-10](http://mattsclassiccameras.com/slr/sears-ksx-super-ricoh-kr-10/)

#### Adapting Lenses

For issues concerning the use of lens adapters, see [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/75526) In particular, [Registration Distance / Flange Focal Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) will be a problem.

The M42 screw mount has a registration distance of 45.46mm. Most commonly-used modern mounts have a shorter registration distance. A notable exception is the Nikon F mount, which has a registration distance of 46.50mm.

While there is an adapter from F-mount to M42 ([eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/332675561406)/[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B2KF67Y)), it appears to *not* be thin enough to maintain infinity focus. An adapter with a corrective lens would be required.

#### Why?

Many old M42 lenses are available with various levels of quality or interesting characteristics. What do you hope to gain by seeking to use a *new* lens with an *old* body?